# Python "Commands out of sync" error inserting bulk into MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I'm currently trying to speed up the process of piping our data through from 3rd party tools. I've written a function to push through insert statements to our MySQL database in bulk, but am getting the following error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now")
```

The function I've written is as follows, taking in record_array (an array of dicts containing the data to be pushed through to the MySQL table) and tablename (a string containing the name of the table):

```
def insert_update_bulk(self, record_array, tablename):
    session = self.Session()
    self.merge_query = ""
    for r in record_array:
        query = '''INSERT INTO {} ('''.format(tablename)
        for k in r.keys():
            query += '{}, '.format(k)
        query = query[:-2] + ''') VALUES ('''
        for v in r.values():
            if type(v) == int:
                query += '{},'.format(v)
            else:
                query += '"{}",'.format(str(v).replace('"', "'").replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', ' '))
        query = query[:-1] + ''') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE '''
        for k in r.keys():
            if type(r[k]) == int:
                query += '{}={},'.format(k, str(r[k]).replace('"', "'")).replace("'None'", 'NULL')
            else:
                query += '{}="{}",'.format(k, str(r[k]).replace('"', "'")).replace("'None'", 'NULL')

        query = query[:-1] + '; '
        self.merge_query += query
    session.execute(self.merge_query.replace('%', '%%'))
    self.Session.close_all()
```

Comment: Please do not create SQL queries by joining strings together. You should always use paramterised queries, otherwise you have a significant security risk from SQL injection.

Comment: The string composition and parsing of your query will mean that each insert is individually compiled for the SQL instance.
In general, if you can wrap the updates into a single transaction, they will complete faster.
Also, if you can impose a single exclusive lock while you are doing the inserts, then the insert speed improves, however this does make the table inaccessible to other connection.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts are you saying there's a way to wrap multiple insert/update statements into a single statement, or just the update part of it?

Comment: Yes! Look in the documentation for "begin Transaction"